# WPF TextBlock Padding is cutting off text

Tags: wpf, padding, textblock

I have a `TextBlock` in a `Grid` with its `Padding` attribute set to 5. Sometimes the last character is cut off, depending on what string the `Text` property is set to.

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="SomeClass">
    <ScrollViewer Padding="5" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label
                Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                Content="SomeLabel"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Padding="5"
                Text="0x0F"
                TextWrapping="Wrap"
                VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</UserControl>
```

When the `Text` is set to `0x0F` the `F` is not visible. When it is set to `0xAB` the string displays just fine. Setting the `Padding` to 0 also makes the string display just fine.

Comment: We need to see all the XAML so we can see what's wrong with your layout logic.

Comment: I've provided a complete example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you describe is obviously a layout bug in WPF (probably in the TextBlock). Whether or not the last letter is wrapped (and cut off) seems to depends on the actual width of the string and the size of the last letter in respect to the size of the padding.

I suggest you report the bug [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/feedback/default.aspx?SiteID=212&wa=wsignin1.0.).

To work around this issue you can use the following code (just put a border around you textblock and set the padding there instead):

```
<Border Padding="5" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
    <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Text="0x0F" TextWrapping="Wrap"
        VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</Border>
```

Comment: Thank you, I will report it as you suggested.

Comment: Reported at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=497453

Answer (score 0):

Make the column of the grid that contains textblock auto size like this

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <TextBlock Grid.COlumn="0" Text="{Binding Path=SomeViewModelProperty}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Wow, I tried your code and get the same result, it cuts off F. This also happens for 0x0b and 0x0d but other hex numbers are displayed properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the height on the TextBlock to 100, does the F then get wrapped?

Comment: This was a good guess, but no, unfortunately I tried what you suggested and the F was not wrapped.

Answer (score 0):

Just increase the Height of the ComboBoxItem , it should solve the problem.